# conditional duplication of rows in matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose A is my data matrix that represents a sample of a household with first element of the row representing the house id and the second column the person id in that house.

```
A = [100 1 56;
     101 1 34;
     101 2 33; 
     102 1 22;
     102 2 55;
     102 3 2]

w = [3 2 1] % weight of each household to generate the synthetic population
```

I would like to expand the sample to create a synthetic population such that my outuput looks like this :

```
100 1 56
100 1 56
100 1 56
101 1 34
101 2 33
101 1 34
101 2 33
102 1 22
102 2 55
102 3  2
```

I have used the following code to repeat all rows in the matrix for a given weight

```
cc = [0 cumsum(w)];
idx = zeros(1,sum(w));

for i=1:length(w)
   idx(cc(i)+1:cc(i+1))=i;
end
weighted_replicated_matrix = A (idx,:)
```

But for my desired output I need to repeat a set of rows. The length of the set of rows depend on the number of person in the household (which could be a separate matrix like w) and the number of times each set is to be repeated is given by the weight matrix.

Any help on the code modification will be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be this:

```
ids = unique(A(:,1));

B = [];
for ii = 1:numel(ids)
    B = [B; repmat( A(A(:,1)==ids(ii),:), w(ii),1)]; %#ok
end
```

Note that this is not very efficient, but that will only be a problem if you have a very large data set that you need to replicate like this very often. For a couple of one-off shots, this will amply suffice.